# Changing Grayscale with a Script

Tags: javascript, html, css

Why does grayscale can be changed using a button:

```
<button type="button" 
onclick="document.getElementById('id1').style.filter = 'grayscale(100%)'">
```

But not if I put it in a script?

```
<script>
document.getElementById("id1").style.filter = "grayscale(100%)";
</script>
```

I'm trying to make an image grayscale 100% by default (Using a script) and then changing it's grayscale property with a button. Button works fine, the script does not.

Comment: maybe you put the script at the start ... before dom loading

Comment: ^, also you didn't put it in a function so it just runs once and then doesn't run again

Comment: You should use CSS.

Comment: Solved. Script location was wrong. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function to change the grayscale, then call this function from the onclick.

The button will be like this tag:

```
<button type="button"onclick="greyScale">
```

And the script tag will be like this tag:

```
<script>
function greyScale()
{
document.getElementById("id1").style.filter="grayscale(100%)";
}
</script>
```